# How to detect available carrier networks?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Is there any way in Android to detect all available carrier networks in the area. I tried to search it from connectivity manager and it seems it only returns active network info. I also tried the telephony manager and it only returns signals and neighbor info of the active carrier (e.g. other signals of same carrier). I would like to create an app that will scan for available cell networks in every country -- like in Settings -- to choose my network when roaming.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know that is not possible, because you can only get the cell info of your SIM carrier, but we have a new method on `TelephonyManager` called `getAllCellInfo ()`.
The problem is that method its only available on API Level 17, only available on devices with Jelly Bean (4.2).

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Ok i tried on 2 devices running Jelly Bean (HTC Legend unofficial and Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1 ROM OTA updated) and the method `getAllCellInfo()` always return NULL. I set all permissions required (Manifest). There are folks with the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619586/android-api-listcellinfo

Answer (score 0):

Even the getAllCellInfo function will never report "all networks" that are in the air at your location, simply because the phone will only listen to / measure on the frequencies / networks that the current serving cell tells it to measure on. Normally this means that it will only measure (and be able to report cells) from the same network as the phone is currently using.

If the phone has lost coverage from its "home PLMN" (home or selected network) it will however periodically do measurements in other frequencies to try to get back to it's "favourite network".

To be able to get lists of all present networks in your area you need to have another kind of device for example a "scanner", which never locks on to any cell, but continuously scans many frequencies to find cells from any network and any radio access technology (GSM/WCDMA LTE for example) within these frequencies.

Or continuously press the "select network" function...

/ Kenneth