# Android API List<cellinfo>

Tags: android

I would like to get the CellInfo data, but the cellinfo.size() always occur
 the NullPointerException in Emulator.

[CellInfo Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo.html)

I am not sure the exception situation, anyone know the reason?

Whether I wrote the wrong code? or anyone met the same exception?

```
    TelephonyManager TM = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    List<CellInfo> cellinfo = TM.getAllCellInfo();
    Log.d("AA",Integer.toString(cellinfo.size()));
```

Comment: are you shure that you use emulator/phone with API level 17?

Comment: YES! I choose the API Level 17 Emulator!

Answer (score 0):

Some telephony information is permission-protected. Your application cannot access the protected information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

`TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` is not implemented on many devices, and the function will always return null.

See my answer here: [getAllCellInfo returns null in android 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1/18688268#18688268)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it worked only on s4.hence had to remove cell info listener( PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO) inorder to work.

Answer (score 0):

`TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` is added in API level 17, so you can use it on Api Level 17 and +.

Also you must add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission to your manifest file:

> **Returns**
>  List of CellInfo or null if info unavailable. 
>   
> Requires
>   Permission: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

[See Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo%28%29)

Comment: Added permission already, but I still got NullPointerException. 
I try it in Samsung Note3 (Android 4.3) this time.

Answer (score 0):

well I had the same trouble! The CellInfo is null, cause we didn't put anything. so i try to help the listener a little bit. i force him to get .getAllCellInfo into the listener. here is what works for me.

```
 class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    int signal;
    String cellList;
    @Override
    public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> cellInfo)
    {
        super.onCellInfoChanged(cellInfo);
        cellInfo = Tel.getAllCellInfo();
        if (cellInfo!=null)
            cellList = cellInfo.toString();
        else cellList="ni mierda";
        mSignalStrengthView.append("" + String.valueOf(cellList));
    }
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
    {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        signal = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()*2-113;
        mSignalStrengthView.append("GSM signal strength is " +    String.valueOf(this.signal));
    }
}
```