# getAllCellInfo returns null in android 4.2.1

Tags: android, telephonymanager

My Android version is 4.2.1 and I am trying to make use of `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` method. In my manifest file I have the `ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES`, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions. However that method returns `null`.

Answer (score 8):

From [`TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getAllCellInfo%28%29) javadoc:

> This is preferred over using getCellLocation although for older devices this may return null in which case getCellLocation should be called.

[Some sources](http://s4gru.com/index.php?/topic/1612-problems-programming-android-signal-strength-reporting-for-lte/?p=93644) report that this method is only implemented on CDMA/LTE devices, and other types of devices (including GSM/LTE ones) will return null. Where implemented, it will return only LTE cells.

`TelephonyManager.getCellLocation()` will return only GSM/UMTS or CDMA cells. It it limited to one cell, the one with which the device is currently registered. This is your safest bet if you are sure your code will only be running on GSM/UMTS or CDMA devices, and if you are only interested in the cell with which the device is currently registered.

To get information about other surrounding cells, use `TelephonyManager.getNeighboringCellInfo()`. However, it is limited to GSM/UMTS cells. Also, its implementation depends on the radio firmware. Most Samsung devices (and quite a few others) will return an empty list.

Conclusion: getting information about nearby cells on Android is pretty messy business at the moment. You may need to use a combination of all three methods to get the information you want, and even that way, some things may be inaccessible.

Answer (score 5):

The following command lists the permissions available on a phone:

```
adb shell pm list permissions -g
```

On the Nexus 4 (4.2.2) **ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES** permission is not listed.

**UPDATE:**

When looking though the master branch of the source code there is no reference to ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES so this appears to be and error in the documentation. In fact the pertinent code only requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and/or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Tracing through the following:

- TelephonyManager
- ITelephony
- PhoneInterfaceManager
- PhoneGlobals
- PhoneFactory
- GsmPhone
- PhoneBase
- ServiceStateTracker

In ServiceStateTracker:

```
/**
 * @return all available cell information or null if none.
 */
public List<CellInfo> getAllCellInfo() {
    return null;
}
```

So it looks like in all cases it will return a null.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43467) is a link to a current defect report.

Comment: My phone is also Nexus and it doesn't list ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES permission. Do you think that on some phone with 4.2 version other than Nexus getAllCellInfo() might work? Did you have a change to check it on some other phone?

Comment: So as I understand this is a bug in API and it is not possible to get the cell infos? I wonder don't they have plans to fix is important bug?

Answer (score -1):

The api states the following:

`GetAllCellInfo` is preferred over using `getCellLocation` although for older devices this may return `null` in which case `getCellLocation` should be called.