# Get WCDMA Signal Strength

Tags: java, android, signal-strength

Hello I'm developing an Android app to monitor RSCP and ECNO for WCDMA network, I tried with the below code and there is no error during build but I'm getting error when I run the app on my phone (Samsung Galaxcy Core Prime).

The Code :

```
    public class SignalStrength extends ActionBarActivity {

    TelephonyManager tManager;
    PhoneStateListener pListener;
    public static String LOG_TAG = "PhoneStateListener";
    public TextView rs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rscp);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signal_strength);
        tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tManager.listen(pListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_signal_strength, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(CellSignalStrengthWcdma signalStrength) {
        //super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged" + signalStrength);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSignalStrengthsChanged: getRscp" + signalStrength.getDbm());
        int ttt = signalStrength.getDbm();
        rs.setText(String.valueOf(ttt));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Is there any errors in the code ??

please help me to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

The new code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signal_strength);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
    CellInfoWcdma cellinfoWcdma = null;
    if(cellLocation!=null){
        cellinfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrengthWcdma = cellinfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=18){
            cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getDbm();
            int ttt = cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getDbm();
            //int cid = cellLocation.getPsc();
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(ttt));
        }

    }
}
```

The new debug log:

```
> 03-15 22:13:21.710  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI 03-15 22:13:21.770 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/ActivityThread﹕
> handleBindApplication:com.asiacell.signalstrength 03-15 22:13:21.800 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕
> getCSCPackageItemText() 03-15 22:13:21.800 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/DisplayManager﹕
> DisplayManager() 03-15 22:13:21.830 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
> 03-15 22:13:21.830  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11348:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
> (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V 03-15 22:13:21.830 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:13:21.830 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
> 03-15 22:13:21.830  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11354:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
> 03-15 22:13:21.830  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:13:21.830 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled 03-15 22:13:21.830  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039:
> Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
> ()V 03-15 22:13:21.830  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e 03-15 22:13:21.840 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 03-15 22:13:21.840  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-15
> 22:13:21.840  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:13:21.840 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-15
> 22:13:21.840  15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 386:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-15 22:13:21.840 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:13:21.940 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling
> debug mode 0 03-15 22:13:21.990 
> 15005-15005/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/Timeline﹕ Timeline:
> Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41eedeb8 time:95899927 03-15
> 22:14:02.329  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕
> Late-enabling CheckJNI 03-15 22:14:02.379 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/ActivityThread﹕
> handleBindApplication:com.asiacell.signalstrength 03-15 22:14:02.409 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕
> getCSCPackageItemText() 03-15 22:14:02.409 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/DisplayManager﹕
> DisplayManager() 03-15 22:14:02.439 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
> 03-15 22:14:02.439  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11350:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
> (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V 03-15 22:14:02.439 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:14:02.439 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
> 03-15 22:14:02.439  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11356:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
> 03-15 22:14:02.439  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:14:02.449 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled 03-15 22:14:02.449  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039:
> Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
> ()V 03-15 22:14:02.449  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e 03-15 22:14:02.449 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 03-15 22:14:02.449  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-15
> 22:14:02.449  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:14:02.449 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-15
> 22:14:02.449  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 386:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-15 22:14:02.449 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:14:02.499 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting
> down VM 03-15 22:14:02.499  15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0x416ebbc0) 03-15 22:14:02.509 
> 15081-15081/com.asiacell.signalstrength E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.asiacell.signalstrength, PID: 15081
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asiacell.signalstrength/com.asiacell.signalstrength.SignalStrength}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.asiacell.signalstrength.SignalStrength.onCreate(SignalStrength.java:32)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5301)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 03-15 22:17:02.385  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.asiacell.signalstrength
> 03-15 22:17:02.415  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText() 03-15
> 22:17:02.425  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/DisplayManager﹕ DisplayManager() 03-15 22:17:02.455 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
> 03-15 22:17:02.455  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11348:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
> (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V 03-15 22:17:02.455 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:17:02.455 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
> 03-15 22:17:02.455  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11354:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
> 03-15 22:17:02.455  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:17:02.465 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled 03-15 22:17:02.465  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039:
> Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
> ()V 03-15 22:17:02.465  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e 03-15 22:17:02.465 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 03-15 22:17:02.465  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-15
> 22:17:02.465  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:17:02.465 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-15
> 22:17:02.465  15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 386:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-15 22:17:02.465 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:17:02.585 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling
> debug mode 0 03-15 22:17:02.645 
> 15297-15297/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/Timeline﹕ Timeline:
> Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41ef2ad8 time:96120583 03-15
> 22:17:54.546  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.asiacell.signalstrength
> 03-15 22:17:54.576  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText() 03-15
> 22:17:54.576  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/DisplayManager﹕ DisplayManager() 03-15 22:17:54.606 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
> 03-15 22:17:54.606  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11348:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
> (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V 03-15 22:17:54.606 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:17:54.606 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
> 03-15 22:17:54.606  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11354:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
> 03-15 22:17:54.606  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:17:54.606 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled 03-15 22:17:54.606  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039:
> Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
> ()V 03-15 22:17:54.606  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e 03-15 22:17:54.616 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 03-15 22:17:54.616  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-15
> 22:17:54.616  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:17:54.616 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-15
> 22:17:54.616  15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 386:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-15 22:17:54.616 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:17:54.716 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling
> debug mode 0 03-15 22:17:54.766 
> 15370-15370/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/Timeline﹕ Timeline:
> Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41ee7198 time:96172707 03-15
> 22:24:10.483  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:com.asiacell.signalstrength
> 03-15 22:24:10.513  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText() 03-15
> 22:24:10.513  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/DisplayManager﹕ DisplayManager() 03-15 22:24:10.543 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
> 03-15 22:24:10.543  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11350:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted
> (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V 03-15 22:24:10.543 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:24:10.543 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
> 03-15 22:24:10.543  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11356:
> Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
> 03-15 22:24:10.543  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000 03-15 22:24:10.553 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled 03-15 22:24:10.553  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9039:
> Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll
> ()V 03-15 22:24:10.553  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e 03-15 22:24:10.553 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations,
> referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
> 03-15 22:24:10.553  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 364:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I 03-15
> 22:24:10.553  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:24:10.553 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find
> method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method
> android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType 03-15
> 22:24:10.553  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY:
> unable to resolve virtual method 386:
> Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I 03-15 22:24:10.553 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing
> opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 03-15 22:24:10.613 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting
> down VM 03-15 22:24:10.613  15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength
> W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> (group=0x416ebbc0) 03-15 22:24:10.613 
> 15519-15519/com.asiacell.signalstrength E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.asiacell.signalstrength, PID: 15519
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asiacell.signalstrength/com.asiacell.signalstrength.SignalStrength}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at com.asiacell.signalstrength.SignalStrength.onCreate(SignalStrength.java:32)
>             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5301)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the Exception? Could you please show your stackTrace?

Comment: Your pListener is null. You have to initialize it, before using listen() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get WCDMA Signal Strength, you can use this code:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    List<CellInfo> cellList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
    CellInfoWcdma cellinfoWcdma = null;
    if(cellList!=null && !cellList.isEmpty()){
        cellinfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
        CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrengthWcdma = cellinfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=18){
            cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getDbm();
        }
    }
```

Note that the `getDbm()` method is only available from API 18 onwards.

**Edit**:You also need to add the following permissions in your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, I've used your code and still the app. being stopped when I try to run it, by the why I'm running the app. on 4.4.4 Android.

I add the new code in the main post.

Comment: I added the debug log in the main post, many thanks for your kind help.

Comment: What is your Activity line 21?

Comment: public TextView rs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rscp);

Comment: put that line inside onCreate() method, after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_signal_strength);`

Comment: Hi, it's working now but I think I'm getting the cellList null or empty, what could be the problem ?         
List<CellInfo> cellList = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();

Comment: According to the documentation: " The list can include one or more of CellInfoGsm, CellInfoCdma, CellInfoLte and CellInfoCdma in any combination. Specifically on devices with multiple radios it is typical to see instances of one or more of any these in the list. In addition 0, 1 or more CellInfo objects may return isRegistered() true.

This is preferred over using getCellLocation although for older devices this may return null in which case getCellLocation should be called. "

Comment: Your device may be old and thus, your list is null. Use getCellLocation() instead.

Comment: I used getCellLocation() and I get the cell id and cell lac, but It's still not working for RSCP, could you please give me a sample code, I used the code in the main post, also the debug log is there.

Comment: By the way my device is Samsung Galaxcy Core Prime which is released on last November and it's running KitKat.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1 for more information. Accept my answer if you think it helped you.