# How to get signal strength android?

Tags: android, signal-strength

[CellSignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html) is the closest to what i need, but the problem i'm facing is that there is no constructor to use the class, and I tried to make a new class and extend it, it didn't work, the android documentation is good, without offering one small piece of code to follow, I don't know what to do.

i'm using API 8, which doesn't support that class, what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<CellInfo> all = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) all.get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
int strengthDbm = cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

should work fine for API 17+. I am not aware of any API to help <17, though.

Comment: i've made a new project with the API 17 to test this. it gives error message "can not resolve symbol context" , the one in the first line.

Comment: The `context` reference there could be your `Activity`, most likely. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work : 

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) activity_main.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Comment: if you are using `Activity` try `getApplicationContext().getSystemService..`

Comment: The "List<CellInfo>" list always returns empty, i read here that it's not implemented on all devices : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1/18688268#18688268

Comment: my phone has android 4.4.4

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
03-28 14:35:42.117 16909-16909/com.example.tene11.lockappnew W/System.err:     at com.example.tene11.lockappnew.Data.SimInfo.getSimInfo(SimInfo.java:29)
03-28 14:35:42.117 16909-16909/com.example.tene11.lockappnew W/System.err:     at com.example.tene11.lockappnew.services.DeviceStatus.onReceive(DeviceStatus.java:98)
03-28 14:35:42.117 16909-16909/com.example.tene11.lockappnew