# Android getAllCellInfo() returns null

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I'm new to android, and I work on a project that goes to collect all cells information that observed by phone. I have used `TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo()` method, but it always returns `null`.

My Code ::

```
public class NetworkCoverageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String str;
    private TextView TV;
    private Button getCellsInfoBtn;
    private TelephonyManager TM;
    private List<CellInfo> cellInfoList;
    private PhoneStateListener PSL;
    private int event;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_network_coverage);

        TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        getCellsInfoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getCellsInfoBtn);
        TM = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PSL = new PhoneStateListener();
        event = PSL.LISTEN_CELL_INFO | PSL.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION;

        getCellsInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                TM.listen(PSL, event);
                cellInfoList = TM.getAllCellInfo();

                if(cellInfoList != null)
                    TV.append("cellInfoList = null");
                else{
                    ...
                }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm working on android 4.4.2 level 17 and set min API level to 17. and I try to collect information from GSM network.

Also, I added the following permission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1

Comment: Some of the devices such as Samsung,Huawei doesn't have these API's which always return null.

Comment: As per the docs: This method is preferred over using getCellLocation(). However, for older devices, getAllCellInfo() may return null. In these cases, you should call getCellLocation() instead. Also, if no info is available, null is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution of my question. that's replaced `getAllCellInfo()` function by `getNeighboringCellInfo()` function, although I am running with android level 17 that should be support `getAllCellInfo()` function and `getNeighboringCellInfo()` function should be no longer supported.
Anyway, the following is the solution.

```
package ayad.bslm.com.networkcoverage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class NetworkCoverageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView TV;
    private TelephonyManager TM;
    private List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighboringCellInfoList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_network_coverage);

        TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        Button getCellsInfoBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getCellsInfoBtn);
        TM = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        getCellsInfoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                neighboringCellInfoList = TM.getNeighboringCellInfo();

                if(neighboringCellInfoList == null)
                    TV.setText("neighboringCellInfoList == null\n");
                else
                    TV.setText("There are " + neighboringCellInfoList.size() + " Cells\n");
            }
        });
    }
}
```