# private class packages like android.telephony/telecom

Tags: java, android, private, telephony

I want to use some methods from `android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthWcdma` however I am getting some errors. I just have the following code:

```
public void calculate(View view) {
    CellSignalStrengthWcdma cell = new CellSignalStrengthWcdma();
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
'CellSignalStrengthWcdma()' is not public in 'android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthWcdma'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

Without creating an object of this class, I cannot use it's methods like `getDbm()`.

How can I use the methods?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a [CellInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfo) you can cast it to `CellInfoWcdma` and then get its signal strength `CellSignalStrengthWcdma`:

```java
if (cellInfo instanceOf CellInfoWcdma) {
  CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrength = ((CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo).getCellSignalStrength();
}
```

**Documentation**

- [CellSignalStrengthWcdma](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/android.telephony.CellSignalStrengthWcdma).
- [How to get CellInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1/18688268#18688268)

Comment: I updated my post: [How to get CellInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541172/getallcellinfo-returns-null-in-android-4-2-1/18688268#18688268)